# Differential equation satisfied by the angle made by the pendulum.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, classical-mechanics

A pendulum of mass $M$ and length $l$ is pulled to an angle $\alpha$ from the
vertical and released from rest. Write down the differential equation satisfied
by the angle $\theta(t)$ made by the pendulum with the vertical at time $t$, using
the principle of conservation of energy. (If $s$ is the arc length measured from
the vertical position, then the velocity $v$ is given by $v = \frac{ds}{dt}$.

how to think?

My attempt is The gravitation force on the object is $mg(l\cos \theta - l\cos \alpha)$ since pendulum is pulled to an angle $\alpha$ from the vertical and then  released. Also $$F = m a = m \frac{dv}{dt} =  m \frac{d^2 s}{dt^2}$$ Now since $s = l \theta \implies ds = l d \theta$, we get $$F = ml^2 \frac{d^2 \theta}{dt^2} = mgl(\cos \theta - \cos \alpha)$$ But the answer is $\frac{1}{2}l^2\big(\frac{d\theta}{dt}\big)^2 = gl(\cos \theta - \cos \alpha)$. Where am i wrong? Please help.

Comment: The forces on the pendulum depend only on its current position, $\theta.$ The starting position, $\alpha,$ is irrelevant. The formula you gave for "the gravitation force" therefore obviously is _not_ a force. It looks like you got force confused with energy.

Comment: Check your units: $mgl$ has dimensions of *energy*, not force. So does $ml^2d^2\theta/dt^2$.

Comment: It looks like you wrote the wrong formula for the second time derivative of $l\theta.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that we need to equate the

- Kinetic energy: $\frac12mv^2=\frac{1}{2}ml^2\big(\frac{d\theta}{dt}\big)^2 $

to the

- Potential energy: $mg\Delta h=mgl(\cos \theta - \cos \alpha)$